# PhP MySQL get ceratin items from database and echo them

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help and I can't figure it out,i tried searching the internet but I found nothing

So I'm using this code from w3schools

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; //Obviously this are set to my parameters
$username = "username"; //Obviously this are set to my parameters
$password = "password"; //Obviously this are set to my parameters
$dbname = "myDB"; //Obviously this are set to my parameters

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM People";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Some code goes here
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

How can I modify this code to echo certain items only?

**EXAMPLE**

I have 10 items in talbe People (Table people contains id,age,name,gender)

I want to echo out 3 out of 10 People by using their ID which are 1 trough 10

I know i can use this `AND id IN(1, 5, 9)";` This just echoes them out 1 after another

Is there a way to echo out id 1 goes here , id 5 goes here and than id 9 goes there like in 3 different places with 3 different codes or something? is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
class people
{

    public function people()
    {
        $sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `people`");
        $sql->execute();

        $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

then when you want certain information you could simply use in say index.php:

```
$fetch = new people();

$info = $fetch->people();
```

you can then run simple echo's such as `$info->name` or `$info->id` etc etc..

Depending on how you're searching for the user you could just add

```
WHERE `userid` = :id
$sql->bindParam(':id', $userid);
```

and add `$userid` into the `people($userid)`

But this will vary depending on how you're pulling out specific users.

Comment: It depends on how you're approaching this. Personally I'd do this via a form.

Comment: Well the idea behind this is,every week I need to pull out 5 to 8 different people.Instead of doing it by hand i just want to give this code the user's ID and those people to get pulled out in their places

Comment: Sounds like you'd be looking into the cronjob side of things for it to be automated at X time on Y day. Could be worth looking into the rand() function to achieve it passing the user ID to the query.

Comment: Can we open a chat so that i can explain it easier to you what I want to do? (Also i have no idea how to open the chat)

Comment: I can't say ive ever used the chat feature either to be honest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130595/discussion-between-innervisions-and-option).

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<?php 

    //using PDO
    try 
    {
       $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbhost=myhost;dbname=mydbname;', 'user','pass');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $getId = $conn->query("
               SELECT * FROM users 
               WHERE id = 1
               AND id = 5
               AND id = 9
               ");

    while ($ids = $getId->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    {
      echo $getId->id . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me at all,it does the same thing that the code from w3schools does, with AND id IN(1, 5, 9)";